# Issue in updating table using php

Tags: php, mysql

Update Page:

```
    <?php

     mysql_connect("localhost","root","");//database connection
     mysql_select_db("basic");

       $data_id = $_GET['id'];
         $order = "select * from user where id=$data_id";       $result=mysql_query($order);

                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) 

                     {
            $fn= $row['First_name'] ;       $ln= $row['last_name'] ;        $s= $row['sex'] ;       $ad= $row['address']; }

     ?>         <form action="form_finalupdate.php" method="GET" >

     <fieldset> <legend>Welcome <?php echo "$fn" ?></legend>


 Update your Information:<br><br>

  First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo "$fn"
 ?>" > &nbsp;  Last Name: <input type="text"  name ="lname"
 value="<?php echo "$ln" ?>" > <br><br>


 Sex:<br> <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" value="<?php echo
 "$s"?>" >Male<br> <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female"
 value="<?php echo "$s" ?>" >Female<br><br>

 Address: <input type=text name="add"value="<?php echo "$ad" ?>" >
 <br><br>


 <input type="submit" value="Update" >

 </fieldset> </form>
```

Finalupdate page:

```
 <?php

 mysql_connect("localhost","root","");//database connection
 mysql_select_db("basic");

         $data_id = $_GET['id'];
            $fn= $row['First_name'] ;       $ln= $row['last_name'] ;        $s= $row['sex'] ;       $ad= $row['address'];

        $order = "UPDATE user 
                  SET First_name='$fn',last_name='$ln',sex='$s',address='$ad'
                  WHERE id='$data_id' ";

$result=mysql_query($order);     ?>
```

Comment: Actually i m trying to update database table and showing values back to normal form. but its giving error in final update.php file saying  Undefined variable: row in C:\xampp\htdocs\dip\form_finalupdate.php on line 8 etc...pls help me

Comment: why would he use set more than once @SunilPachlangia ?

Comment: if you think any change in code then  pls comment

Comment: well where is $row. Where was life breathed into it

Comment: you want a $row. You don't have one

Comment: so wer to add it.jst edit code

Comment: let me put it this way. You might have a `$row` on another page. But on this page (`Finalupdate page`) you don't have one. So you certainly don't have `$fn` etc

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Note: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, they will be removed from PHP in future versions and your code will stop working then. You should not write new code using them, use [`mysqli_*` or PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead.

Comment: this code is surely begging for injection attacks

Comment: @Drew Does it do it on its knees?

Comment: it does it in a box, it does it with a fox

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$data_id = $_GET['id'];

> $fn= $row['First_name'] ;        $ln= $row['last_name'] ;         $s=
>   $row['sex'] ;        $ad= $row['address'];

Well you aren't having any "$row" variable in "form_finalupdate.php". Try $_GET instead.

P.S: Passing data directly to the query can lead to SQL injection. Please use corrective measure or use PDO instead.